# Apple Mach-O Linker Errors

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I was wondering what I should do to fix these linker errors...

```
Ld ... normal armv7
cd ...
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L...-esjhccmwalrxrdfeduounwwkhaef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F ...-esjhccmwalrxrdfeduounwwkhaef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist ...-esjhccmwalrxrdfeduounwwkhaef/Build/Intermediates/... -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker ...

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController setupCapture] in AVController.o
  "_CATransform3DIdentity", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController setupCapture] in AVController.o
  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVController.o
  "_kCAGravityResizeAspectFill", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController setupCapture] in AVController.o
  "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVController.o
  "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVController.o
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVController.o
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVController.o
  "_CATransform3DRotate", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController setupCapture] in AVController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CALayer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AVController.o
  "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVController.o
  "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress", referenced from:
  -[MyAVController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know I need to add some framework, but I can't figure out what.

If you need any additional info, I can provide it.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing a media project and have you linked the AVFoundation framework?

Comment: I am displaying a camera in my app, and (I am a newbie to iOS Development) how do I know if I linked the AVFoundation Framework? @Kevin

Comment: Click on your project (blue top file), open the Build Phases and look at Link Binary with Libraries

Comment: Now I am down to 13. What other Frameworks do I need to add? Thank you all so much!!! @Kevin

Comment: Update the screen with 13 then :)

Comment: Sorry about that, doing it now! EDIT: Did it!

Comment: AVFoundation, Core Media, and Core Video I would guess. It should be in the tutorial though.

Comment: Down to 0 ? or there is more ?

Comment: @user2957713 I am checking, Xcode isn't seeing my iPad, so hold on for one sec.

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks so much to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're forgetting to import some frameworks into your project: namely the `AVFoundation` framework.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't import frameworks 
if you don't know how to do so 
here is a step by step guide

Yous should add CoreVideo , CoreMedia frameworks and AVFoundation.

http://thinketg.com/xcode-4-tips-adding-frameworks-to-your-project/